# Normals shows up as single while they should be double

Tags: normals

If I create a plane, subdivide it in halfs, grab the edge in the middle and pull it upwards and then inspect the normals, they show up like this:

[image: Model being edited]

Now, I do not see double normals at any vertex. Still, the rendered output suggests that the normals where the faces meat eachother are different:

[image: Rendered output]

Now, which normal is applied on each of those two faces? The average of the vertex normals?

Comment: This looks..normal. Pan around the shape and see if you get and really dark spots. A face's normal display color changes depending on the angle your looking at it.

Comment: The average normal of all vertices on a face is used for shading. If you want the vertex normal the shading would have to interpolate. Select "smooth" (shading) for the object in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Auto smooth is required to display individual normals.

[image]